# PowerShell script using array to check if file/folders exist

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have created a PowerShell script to check if specific folders/zip files exist at a location and then delete them if they do. Their names are hard-coded into an array and then searched at the destination for presence and then are deleted. This is how it flows:

1. check for the files that exist,
2. print "no matching folder/files exist" to logs, if no matching names are found at destination
3. print names to logs of existing folder/files
4. delete matching files.

It works fine but I want to turn the cmdlets to function as opposed to writing repetitive code. Additionally, it needs exception handling but I'd like to try that myself once I have a working function for lookup and delete.

My code:

```
[string[]]$folderArray = ("folder1","folder2","zipfile1","zipfile2")

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Force |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -in $folderArray } |
    Select-Object FullName |
    Write-Output >> $log

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Force | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -in $folderArray } |
    % { Remove-Item $_.FullName -Recurse -Force }
```

Comment: First of all, have a look at the official doco re functions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 0):

So, by wrapping your code in a function and adding parameters, it can look like:

```
function Foo
{
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [string]$path,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [string]$log,
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateNotNull()]
    [string[]]$folderArray
  )

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -force |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -in $folderArray } |
    Select-Object FullName |
    Write-Output >> $log

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Force | 
    Where-Object { $_.Name -in $folderArray } |
    % { Remove-Item $_.FullName -Recurse -Force }
}
```

Comment: thanks Max, but I need a function that does the lookup and deletion instead of writing the two fairly similar Get-ChildItem commands in my code. Once, I am done with this function, I need to add exception handling where it should print the names of folders/files that are found, or else print "no matching items found in the destination location".